# naming a variable using a loop with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am having some trouble getting a loop to work. I am using the loop to match array values to variations of the variable `test`. However, I am not sure how to properly go about this. I am making a quiz about Star Wars, and tried to refine the original code through a loop (commented out). Any help would be much appreciated for this amateur coder!

```
for (i=0; i<2;i++;){
    test=document.myForm.elements[i].value;
    if (test[i] ==answers[i]){
        ++corr;
    }
    else ++incorr;
}
    /*test0=document.myForm.elements[0].value;
    if (test0.toLowerCase()=="chewbacca"){
        ++corr;
    }
    else ++incorr;
    test1=document.myForm.elements[1].value;
    if (test1.toLowerCase()=="princess leia"){
        ++corr;
    } else ++incorr;
    test2=document.myForm.elements[2].value;
    if (test2.toLowerCase()=="han solo"){
        ++corr;
    }
    else ++incorr;
    test3=document.myForm.elements[3].value;
    if (test3.toLowerCase()=="rey"){
        ++corr;
    }
    else ++incorr; */
    location.reload();
    alert("You got " + corr/(incorr+corr)*100 + " percent correct!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value extracted inside for loop is not a array  but rather a simple value, so dont try to access it like a array `test[i]`.

also use `===` when comparing the variables for strict comparing else you will get undesired results.

```
for (var i=0; i<2; i++;) {
  test=document.myForm.elements[i].value;
  if (test === answers[i]) {
    ++corr;
  }
  else ++incorr;
}
```

*Note: For better performance run your script in strict mode, `use strict;`, which would enforce you to declare all variables before using them. ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode*